# Separate versions of Python on same computer won't import same modules

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7, python-idle

I've been coding in Python 3.7.2 as my usual, but an API that I really want for my code only supports up to 3.6 (and does not support 2.7). I downloaded Python 3.6.4 to my computer, which also downloads a separate instance of the IDLE (not a problem). If I try to import something like numpy to my code in 3.7 (ex. import numpy as np) then it works as expected. However, if I do the same in the 3.6 IDLE I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

I think that it's a path problem but I'm unsure on how to fix it, and I can't find a solution to this problem elsewhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: every version has own folder with modules and you have to install modules in  every version separatelly. Sometime module from one version may not work with other version. On Linux Python creates `pip3.7` and `pip3.6` to install modules in different version. Or you can use `python3.7 -m pip install ...` and `python3.6 -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Get the location of the python executable from IDLE

```
import sys

print(sys.executable) # e.g. /Users/jk/.../bin/python
```

Step 2: Run the `pip` in the same folder as the one returned above.

```
/Users/jk/.../bin/pip install numpy
```

P.S. It's better to maintain libraries independently for each distribution, or even better use `virtualenv` or `conda` to create environments.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install numpy specifically for python3.6:

`python3.6 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: I get the message: 'python3.6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I would also prefer a solution so I don't have to do this for every library I've ever used.

Comment: If you know where your python3.6 executable is, you can call it directly from there or add it to your path